# Rotation Formula for Value of t in Parametric Equations/Bezier Curve

Tags: rotations, parametric, curves, bezier-curve

When working with parametric equations of a bezier curve, I know that when the image is rotated at an angle, you would use to find the new coordinates:

$\ \left(x\cos  θ - y\sin  θ, x\sin  θ + y\cos  θ\right) $

I have a bezier curve and when only$\ x $ is known I use a polynomial equation solver to solve for$\ t $. I then use that to find$\ y $.

Let's say I have on my curve when $\ t = .24 , x = .36, y = -.17 $

Then I rotate my curve at an angle of 30 degrees.  I could use the rotation equation to find the new coordinates of both$\ x $ and$\ y $ at$\ t $, but that is not what I want to do. I want to find both$\ t $ and$\ y $ when$\ x $ is at the same value of $\ x=.36 $

I know I could find$\ t $ again using the new equation output by the rotation at 30 degrees and use the polynomial equation solver all over again to find$\ t $, and then$\ y $, but is there an easier way?

Is there some formula like there is for the$\ \left(x,y\right)$ coordinates for rotating the value of$\ t $ at an angle?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly (and I'm not sure that I do), then the short answer is "no" -- there is no simple formula for the new $t$ value.